# Solidify but not solidify

Tags: modeling

is there a why to make this thing solid? It has many holes and it's hollow inside.

[image]

Many thanks!

It has thickness, but I just want to make it a solid piece.

Comment: Mesh models are always hollow, this is how they are build. Thickness is always simulated. Please specify why you need it to be solid in order for us to help better (3D print, holes in mesh looks bad/incorrect when rendered, need to cut the model in 2, subsurface material setup)

Answer (score 0):

In the Edit mode with the Mesh Select Mode = Vertex
Deselect all verts (A)
Open the Select drop down menu.
Click: Select All By Trait and then click Non Manifold
Hit F to fill all of the holes

At this point you might want to create a New vertex group or just go straight into materials and with the Mesh Select Mode switched to Faces assign all of these faces to a new Material called "inside" which you might want to make matte black.

You may also want to scale them down while they're all still selected to give a greater depth, probably not on the Z axis: S shift-Z

Last thing: I'd save it before doing any of this just in case you can always Revert

Beautiful model, BTW